# How to fix the following PHP Warning?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an old project which is built on `Laravel 5.2` The application was attacked and site was down. I removed the infected code, But now I am getting the following error:

> PHP Warning:  require(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php
>   on line 60

The following code is in the file where the error is:

```
protected function loadConfigurationFiles(Application $app, RepositoryContract $repository)
    {
        foreach ($this->getConfigurationFiles($app) as $key => $path) {
            $repository->set($key, require $path);
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you've cleaned the live site because you don't have any other copy of the project? No local copies, version control or backup?

Comment: if deployed by git, maybe do a `git reset --hard` ,be carefull as this will delete your own un-committed changes. Allways make a copy and make sure your changes (and your changes alone) are committed :).

Comment: It looks like you have removed one of the required configuration files. You can compare the files you have now with the original list at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2/config

Comment: "I removed the infected code". As @ÁlvaroGonzález says, and no staging machine to re-rsync the current live state from? As well as that, I'd also recommend having version control on live for easy rollback of changes and investigating unexpected changes if they happen. Hope all gets resolved.

Comment: @Álvaro González @ Nick I had the full project in bitbucket. I have also deployed a fresh copy, it's just I couldn't access the code that time and just removed the infected code because it was urgent. Just wanted to know what might be the problem.